# use git fork as gradle dependency - KMM Project

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, git-fork

I am trying to add my git fork (https://github.com/OctagonMobile/Nier-Visualizer) as gradle dependency as I need to change some code in original repo.

So I am trying to use jitpack.io, which is not working for me.
I have added mavel url 'https://jitpack.io' in root build.gradle.kts file.
[image]

and in android app's build.gradle.kts file I've added dependency as implementation("com.github.OctagonMobile:Nier-Visualizer:0.1.4")
[image]

But Idk for some reason, its not downloading the dependency. I get error "Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/OctagonMobile/Nier-Visualizer/0.1.4/Nier-Visualizer-0.1.4.pom'".

Please help thanks in advance. I am new to android so please go easy on me :p

Comment: The build for 0.1.4 is failing on Jitpack https://jitpack.io/#OctagonMobile/Nier-Visualizer